# ¿Por qué BigDecimal me elimina los primeros ceros de un número que quiero guardarle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bigdecimal, concat

```
public static BigDecimal getPorceparLeadingZero(BigDecimal bd) {
    if (bd.compareTo(new BigDecimal(100)) > 0) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000");
        return new BigDecimal(df.format(bd).concat("000000"));
    }else {
        String number = String.valueOf(bd);
        return new BigDecimal(number.concat("000000"));
    }

}
```

Me devuelve el número que le pase al método, por ejemplo, lo que yo quiero es esto: *075000000*, le paso como parámetro el "*75*" y el método me tiene que formatear el número como yo se lo indico, y en efecto, me lo hace:

"`df.format(bd)`", luego concateno: `df.format(bd)`, y eso se lo paso al constructor del BigDecimal:

`new BigDecimal(df.format(bd).concat("000000"));`

Pero luego, cuando imprime, es esto: *75000000*, solo el número "*75*" más la concatenación, el BigDecimal me elimina el primer cero...

**Muchas gracias por sus ayuda, estaré esperando respuestas, del por qué y cómo lo haría.**

Comment: Debes devolverlo en un string, en los campos numéricos se omite los ceros a la izquierda

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195821/bigdecimal-omitting-leading-

Comment: Y si solo lo puedo enviar en un objeto número? (En el formato 07500000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu método debe quedar de la siguiente forma, debes devolver un string en vez de **BigDecimal** para poder mostrarlo con 3 cifras.
Si lo que quieres es tener un valor de tipo **BigDecimal** con ceros a la izquierda es imposible, ya que los ceros a la izquierda no cuentan. Solamente se pueden mostrar ceros a la izquierda para visualizarlos, más no para guardarlos.

También tenías un error en tu if, ahora quedó así `if (bd.compareTo(new BigDecimal(100)) < 0)` antes estaba así `if (bd.compareTo(new BigDecimal(100)) > 0)`

```
  static String getPorceparLeadingZero(BigDecimal bd) {
        if (bd.compareTo(new BigDecimal(100)) < 0) {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000");
            return df.format(bd).concat("000000");
        }else {
            String number = String.valueOf(bd);
            return number.concat("000000");
        }
    }
```